# Process custom annotation in build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, annotations

Is it possible to process custom annotation in build.gradle? Currently, I am processing them using Reflections API in some java file. If it helps, I am processing them like this:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(".*");        
Set<Class<?>> flagAnnotatedClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Flags.class);
for (Class cl : flagAnnotatedClasses) {
  /** Get all the flags for a particular class annotated with @Flag. */
  Annotation[] flags = cl.getAnnotationsByType(Flag.class);
  for (Annotation flag : flags) {
    String key = ((Flag) flag).key();
    String value = ((Flag) flag).value();
    System.out.println("key:"+key+", value:"+value);
  }
}
```

Can this be done in the build.gradle? I want this to be done in build.gradle so that I can throw GradleException while processing.